# how can i post the variable value in another form without using submit

Tags: php, post, http-post

I am trying to echo `$_POST['admin_name'];` on next page but it's not working.

How can I do this?

```
if(($a_name==$adminname)&&($pass_word==$pass)) {
    if($a_name=="goher") {
        $_POST['admin_name']=$a_name;
        echo "<script>window.location='home.php'</script>";
    }
    else {
       $_POST['admin_name']=$a_name;
       echo "<script>window.location='upload.php'</script>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<script>window.location='signin.php?msg=Try Again'</script>";
}
```

Comment: Post data is sent only when form is submitted. Use `$_SEESION` instead http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: pass it through the URI ... just like you're passing that Try again msg  at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning something to `$_POST` does not make the data available on some other page (you don't even POST in your case).

I think what you want is `$_SESSION` - when using sessions the data you stored there will be available on subsequent page loads (assuming you always call `session_start()`).